# Gorilla mux json header for all routes golang

Tags: go, mux

Is there a way to set json header to all routes?

```golang
func Ping(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

  json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(map[string]string{"Status": "OK"})
}
func Lol(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  rw.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

  json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(map[string]string{"Status": "OK"})
}
```

not to duplicate this

```golang
json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(map[string]string{"Status": "OK"})
```

Comment: You can write your own middleware function for that: a function that takes a `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` and returns another value of the same function type. Then apply wrap the handlers of interest in that middleware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`middleware`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#middleware) to add `Content-Type: application/json` header to each handler

```golang
func contentTypeApplicationJsonMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then register the [`middleware`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#middleware) to [`gorilla/mux`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) as below

```golang
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/", handler)
r.Use(contentTypeApplicationJsonMiddleware)
```